# What happens when we have a rank-deficient coefficient matrix of over-determined system but the rank of augmented equals the number of variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Suppose an over-constrained system as
$$Ax=b$$
where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $m\gt n$. Let's consider a special scenario, that coefficient matrix $A$ is rank-deficient with $\text{rank}($A$)=n-1$, but the augmented matrix $\text{rank}([A|b])=n$. So now we have $n$ independent functions and $n$ variables, does this mean we are gonna have a unique solution here? This makes me feel like the system is actually a well-determined system.

But for an example,
$$\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 2  \\
1 & 2  \\
1 & 2 
\end{array}\right]x=\left[\begin{array}{l}
3   \\
4   \\
1 
\end{array}\right]$$
Here, $\text{rank}(A)=1$,$\text{rank}([A|b])=2$. We now have two independent equations and two variables. However, we can directly see that each equation is contradictory to each other, as we will get $0+0=3$ from these 3 equations. Then we seems to have no solution here.

Meanwhile, there is no way that a vector $b$ that linearly independent from the column vectors from $A$ lies in the column space of $A$. So I must have misunderstood something here. Could anyone help me out of here? How should I classify this linear equations here? It's over-determined or well-determined?

Answer (score 1):

If ${\rm rank} A = n - 1$ and ${\rm rank} (A |b) = n$, that means that ${\rm rref} (A|b)$ has a pivot in the augmented column. This is not hard to show. Because of this, the system is inconsistent and has no solution.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer! I think I get your point. But I also want to know what is wrong with my instinct about the example in the question that "2 independent variables and 2 independent equations", but still it's not gonna give us a unique solution here. Why is that? 

Like, if $rank(A)=rank([A|b])=n$,  for this case, I think we get a unique solution here.  Why in both of these examples we have "2 independent variables and 2 independent equations", but the solutions of them are totally different. (Sorry, I know this question might be dumb, but I just don't get it)

Comment: I think I get it. Although we have the same number of independent equations as the number of variables, the system then is inconsistent, which can't be solved.